# Ubuntu 18.04.1 - TP-LINK TL-WN821N not ready on boot

Tags: wireless, usb, tp-link

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 system with TP-LINK TL-WN821N USB wireless adapter.
When I boot the PC - the network connection fails and it seems the device is not properly configured at boot time.

Below is the dmesg entries in relation to the driver and device **after boot, before I reinsert** the device in USB:

```
$ dmesg | egrep 'RTL8192EU|rtl8xxxu|wlx503eaa683858|wlan0'
[   15.136988] usb 1-1.2: RTL8192EU rev B (SMIC) 2T2R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[   15.136989] usb 1-1.2: RTL8192EU MAC: 50:3e:aa:68:38:58
[   15.136990] usb 1-1.2: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[   16.534107] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
[   18.184522] rtl8xxxu 1-1.2:1.0 wlx503eaa683858: renamed from wlan0
[   31.048250] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[   31.065191] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[   31.152137] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[   45.484503] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[   45.507480] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[   45.712038] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[   45.919860] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[   46.120026] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[   47.416410] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[   47.439340] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[   47.640024] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[   47.844024] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[   48.048024] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[   49.744430] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[   49.767461] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[   49.968039] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[   50.172021] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[   50.376027] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[   52.560544] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[   52.583199] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[   52.784123] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[   52.988016] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[   53.192025] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[   63.387828] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[   63.399472] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[   63.600037] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[   63.804143] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[   64.012020] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[   70.002702] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[   71.204165] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[   71.215803] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[   71.416021] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[   71.620018] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[   71.824027] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[   83.024639] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[   83.047235] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[   83.248078] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[   83.452135] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[   83.656063] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[   96.003194] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[   97.180264] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[   97.192734] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[   97.396054] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[   97.600066] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[   97.804039] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[  108.992686] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[  109.015683] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  109.216071] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[  109.420060] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[  109.624075] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[  122.004113] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[  123.186001] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[  123.197695] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  123.400084] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[  123.604032] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[  123.808081] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[  134.992680] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[  135.015243] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  135.216070] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[  135.420078] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[  135.624045] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[  142.818088] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[  142.859679] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[  144.043660] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[  144.055299] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  144.256074] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[  144.460083] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[  144.664066] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[  145.944530] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[  145.967932] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  146.168030] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[  146.372075] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[  146.576069] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[  148.264697] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[  148.287274] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  148.488061] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[  148.692066] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[  148.896074] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[  151.088630] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[  151.111758] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  151.312040] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[  151.516057] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[  151.720091] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[  161.932074] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[  161.943681] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  162.144067] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[  162.348066] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[  162.556058] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[  169.003584] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[  190.399551] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[  190.411477] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  190.612072] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 2/3)
[  190.816068] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 3/3)
[  191.020067] wlx503eaa683858: authentication with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 timed out
[  200.825695] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[  200.879731] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[  212.101573] usb 1-1.2: RTL8192EU rev B (SMIC) 2T2R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[  212.101575] usb 1-1.2: RTL8192EU MAC: 50:3e:aa:68:38:58
[  212.101578] usb 1-1.2: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[  213.206188] rtl8xxxu 1-1.2:1.0 wlx503eaa683858: renamed from wlan0
[  213.235390] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[  213.251391] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
[  213.307677] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa683858: link is not ready
```

**after reinsert**:

```
[  231.250273] wlx503eaa683858: authenticate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32
[  231.261953] wlx503eaa683858: send auth to 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  231.263437] wlx503eaa683858: authenticated
[  231.268041] wlx503eaa683858: associate with 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (try 1/3)
[  231.278068] wlx503eaa683858: RX AssocResp from 7c:8b:ca:c1:03:32 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[  231.279819] usb 1-1.2: rtl8xxxu_bss_info_changed: HT supported
[  231.281176] wlx503eaa683858: associated
[  231.412233] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx503eaa683858: link becomes ready
```

Quite strange case and I am not even sure where to begin investigating from, because after reinsert in USB it starts working right away...

Answer (score 0):

The issue started after I rebooted from Windows to Ubuntu, seems that Windows "breaks" the device and I need to plugin/plugout it so it can authenticate. The other thing that got "broken" is the wifi speed.
Before I booted to Windows it was ~11mbps and now it is hardly 8-9mbps
I regret I booted into Windows...
I checked on several forums, but I can not configure any options for the wifi adapter (switch to wifi n mode, or change its power options).